# Apply re.compile on a string to parse to a desired result

Tags: python, regex, xml, text-files

I have recently started learning regex and bit stuck in this project. Actually I am trying to convert a text file to xml and the content of the text file is:

Name: Alex Company: X

Name: Braun Company Y

As per requirement the desired result in xml should be like as:

```
    <celldata>
    <name>Braun</name>
    <company>Y</company>
    </celldata>
```

I have tried many times and as of now my regex code is like this:

```
    rex = re.compile(r'''(?P<title>Name
        |Company)
        \s*:?\s*
        (?P<value>.*)
        ''',re.VERBOSE)
```

After executing this I am and getting the result as:

```
    <root>
    <celldata>
    <name>Alex Company: X</name>
    </celldata>

    <celldata>
    <name>Braun Company: Y</name>
    </celldata>

    </root>
```

Please tell me how to do this as I am stuck. I don't know what can be the regex pattern to traverse my desired xml pattern.

Comment: the last `.*` eats the rest of the line...

Comment: I'm looking at your question history and noticing that you've never up-voted or accepted an answer...?  For StackOverflow to work you need to up-vote all answers that were helpful (the up-arrow next to the number left of each answer), and accept the answer that solved your question (the checkmark to the left of answers).  That way your question will be useful to future visitors (they'll see what worked), and answerers will get points (which makes us feel all warm and fuzzy and wanting to help more people).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat data
Name: Alex Company: X
Name: Braun Company Y
$ cat p.py 
import re

with open('data', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r'^\s*Name\s*:?\s*(.*)Company\s*:?\s*(.*)$', "<celldata><name>\\1</name><company>\\2</company></celldata>", line.strip()))
$ python3 p.py 
<celldata><name>Alex </name><company>X</company></celldata>
<celldata><name>Braun </name><company>Y</company></celldata>
$
```

Comment: I tried your code and its working fine but I don't kow how to integrate this to my code to get the tree. Because the parameters 'title' and 'value' is missing to satisfy my code. I am using the title and value to add the titles and values to a xml tree using the following code: title = m.group('title')
    e = ET.SubElement(celldata, title)
    e.text = m.group('value')
    e.tail = '\n' So how to add your code to my xml tree as <name>---</name> and <company></company>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
rex = re.compile(r'''
    ^Name:?
    \s*
    (?P<name>\w+)
    \s+
    Company:?
    \s*
    (?P<company>\w+)
    $
    ''',re.VERBOSE)
```

if there can be spaces before the `:` I would use `[\s:]*` (even though it technically would match multiple colons..)

Usage would typically be something like:

```
for line in lines:
    m = rex.match(line)
    if m:
        output.write("""
        <celldata>
          <name>{name}</name>
          <company>{company}</company>
        </celldata>
        """.format(**m.groupdict())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but actually I am writing the value to a xml tree using title and company

Comment: title = m.group('title')
       e = ET.SubElement(celldata, title)
           e.text = m.group('value')
              e.tail = '\n'

Comment: I think how to add the <name> and <company> tags the xml tree because trying your code gives: <Braun>Braun</Braun> <X>X</X> . But I want it should be <name>Braun</name><company>X</X>. Please tell me how to add the name and company to the values

Comment: I think how to add the <name> and <company> tags the xml tree because trying your code gives: <Braun>Braun</Braun> <X>X</X> . But I want it should be <name>Braun</name><company>X</company>. Please tell me how to add the name and company to the values

Comment: I've updated my answer with example usage (but if you're having trouble at that level you might want to find a tutorial before moving on..)